Freezing issue during Ubuntu installation on HP EliteBook 8440p
I am encountering an issue while trying to install Ubuntu on my HP EliteBook 8440p laptop. The machine's specifications are as follows:
Processor: Intel Core i5
RAM: 8 GB DDR3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics
During the boot process for installation, my PC freezes at a certain point (screen is stuck or unresponsive).
I have tried the following steps without success

You've sort of limited us in what help we can provide; you've not told us which Ubuntu product & release you're using, what checks you performed of ISO/media etc.  We don't know which installer you're using (there are many selected by ISO/image you download and you've not told us what Ubuntu product/release you're using), nor if any system logs, or installer messages were examined for clues.  Even if the GUI freezes did you try exploring from terminal? directly commanding kernel (bypassing your screen/stuck-UI) etc?  You mention following steps but don't say what steps you followed??

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
